# Spring Webflux does not respect configuration for database name MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-webflux

I am trying to implement a reactive application with Spring Webflux and MongoDB.
I have the following configuration in application.properties file:

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=my-db
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:pass@host:port/my-db
```

However, when I try save some document to the MongoDB I am getting the following error:

```
backend_1   | Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'not authorized on test to execute command { insert: "user", ordered: true, $db: "test" }' on server database:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on test to execute command { insert: \"user\", ordered: true, $db: \"test\" }", "code" : 13, "codeName" : "Unauthorized" }
backend_1   |   at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:179) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
backend_1   |   at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:370) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
```

I simply can not understand why the driver does not respect the configuration for the database name and tries to insert into the database test (and thus fail).
Am I missing something?

One more thing is that I am using the Java backend and MongoDB within a separate containers with docker compose.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for the authentication issue.
It was the authSource that I was missing, so I added it in the database URI and it worked.

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:pass@host:port/my-db?authSource=admin
```

However I still do not understand why the documents that my Java backend creates are being inserted in test database and not the database that I configured to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in application.properties file:

```
# MongoDB
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=my-db
spring.data.mongodb.username=username
spring.data.mongodb.password=password
```